# Find probability it takes less time to send letters according to a Poisson process with intensity $1$, then send them one by one with intensity $5$.

Tags: probability, poisson-process

At the center of espionage in Kznatropsk one is thinking of a new method
for sending Morse telegrams. Instead of using the traditional method,
that is, to send letters in groups of 5 according to a Poisson process with
intensity $1$, one might send them one by one according to a Poisson process
with intensity $5$. Before deciding which method to use one would like to
know the following: What is the probability that it takes less time to send
one group of $5$ letters the traditional way than to send $5$ letters the new
way (the actual transmission time can be neglected).

I tried to solve this problem for a very long time, but I don’t understand how to find this probability.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N(t)$ be a Poisson process with intensity $5$ and $M(t)$ a Poisson process with intensity $1$. For a fixed time $t$, the probability there are at least $5$ arrivals in $M(t)$ is 
$$
1 - e^{-5t}\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{(5t)^k}{k!}.
$$
Let $T$ be the time of the first arrival in $N(t)$, then $T$ has $\mathsf{Exp}(1)$ distribution. So for each $t>0$ we have $\mathbb P(T>t) = e^{-t}$. Since $N(t)$ and $M(t)$ are independent, we may compute the probability that there are at least $5$ arrivals in $M(t)$ before the first arrival in $N(t)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \mathbb P(M(t) \geqslant 5, N(t) = 0)\ \mathsf dt &= \int_0^\infty \left(1 - e^{-5t}\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{(5t)^k}{k!} \right)e^{-t}\ \mathsf dt = \frac{3125}{7776}.
\end{align}

Comment: thanks for the answer. But are you sure about that  $$1 -e^{-5t}\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{(5t)^k}{k!} $$ Maybe $$1 -e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{(t)^k}{k!} $$ ?

Comment: I think you have found the probability of five slow quintets arriving before one fast single letter.

Comment: @Empy2 You are correct, I misread the question. It should be fixed now.